# Jquery Datatables - numeric column sorted as string

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatables

I have this datatable:

```
var dataTable = $('#statistics-table').DataTable({
    paging: false,
    searching: false,
    info: false,
    order: [[2, "desc"]],
    columns: [
        {
            title: "Bid Price",
            data: "Bid"
        },
        {
            title: "Ask Price",
            data: "Ask"
        },
        {
            title: "Profit",
            data: {
                _: "Profit.display",
                sort: "Profit.sort"
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**The problem** is that the `Profit` column is sorted as a string: [View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbTiY.png)

Here is where I set the properties. One for the user's view and one for the sorting (following the example [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/orthogonal-data.html))

```
rows.every(function () {
        var data = this.data();
        var minimalAsk = formatNumber(lowestValuesByCurrency[currency].Ask);
        if (data.Ask !== minimalAsk) {
            var profit = formatNumber(data.Bid - minimalAsk);
            var profitPercent = formatNumber((profit / minimalAsk) * 100);

            if (profit > 0) {
                data.Profit.display = `<strong class="increasing">+${profit} (+${profitPercent}‰)</strong>`;
            } else {
                data.Profit.display = `<strong class="decreasing">${profit} (${profitPercent}‰)</strong>`;
            }

            data.Profit.sort = Number(profit);
        } else {
            data.Profit.display = "Most cheap Ask";
            data.Profit.sort = 0;
        }

        this.data(data);
    });

dataTable.draw();
```

As I debug I can see that `Profit.sort` **is a number** and not a string ([Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhRsz.png)). Why is it continuing to sort it like it's a string?

Comment: try add `type: 'num'` to your Profit columns definition...

Comment: This worked flawlessly. Thank you very much!

Comment: @davidkonrad I would answer the question with your comment. It helped me too.

Comment: @davidkonrad man ! your comment helped me. Thanks a ton for saving my time. Make it as answer bro!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the comment by @davidkonrad into an answer

Explicitly defining the `type` of a column as `num` will force numeric sorting when in client-side processing mode.

In `columnDefs`:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "num", "targets": 0 }
  ]
} );
```

Or in `columns`:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "columns": [
    { "type": "html" },
    null,
    null,
    null,
    null
  ]
} );
```

Examples and reference from https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type